# Update d3 vertical tree with rectangular nodes from v3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been trying to refactor my d3 code from version 3 to later versions I've seen a few examples online and I've tried to implement it with no luck, my second approach was to use an example (https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/1a96af738c89b88723eb63456beb6510)and try to manipulate it (changing orientation and nodes to rectangle) but this is also not going well any help will be much appreciated

Old code

```
 var controlsData = data
    var margin = {top: -95, right: 440, bottom: 20, left: 440},
        width = 1000 - margin.right - margin.left,
        height = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      // Data
      var data = {
          name: null,
          children: controlsData,
      };
      
      var root = data[0]
      
      var i = 0,
          duration = 750,
          rectW = 80,
          rectH = 30;
          root;
          

      var tree = d3.layout.tree().nodeSize([90, 40]);
      var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal().projection(function (d) {
          return [d.x + rectW / 2, d.y + rectH / 2];
      });

      var svg = d3.select("#explorer-graph-container").append("svg")
      .call((zm = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 1]).on("zoom", redraw)))
      .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMax meet")
      .attr("viewBox", "0 0 1000 520")
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      //necessary so that zoom knows where to zoom and unzoom from
      zm.translate([450, -90]);    

      data.x0 = 0;
      data.y0 = height / 2;

      function collapse(d) {
          if (d.children) {
          d._children = d.children;
          d._children.forEach(collapse);
          d.children = null;
          }
      }


      data.children.forEach(collapse);
      update(data);

      d3.select("#body").style("height", "1000px");

      function update(source) {
          // Compute the new tree layout.
          var nodes = tree.nodes(data).reverse(),
          links = tree.links(nodes);

          // Normalize for fixed-depth.
          nodes.forEach(function (d) {
            d.y = !d.depth ? d.depth * 0 : d.depth * 100;
          });

          // Update the nodes…
          var node = svg.selectAll("g.node").data(nodes, function (d) {
          return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
          });

          // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
          var nodeEnter = node
          .enter()
          .append("g")
          .attr("class", "node")
          .attr("transform", function (d) {
              return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")";
          })
          .on("click", d => {
           
            if (d.children) {
                d._children = d.children;
                d.children = null;
            } else {
                d.children = d._children;
                d._children = null;
            }
            // If the node has a parent, then collapse its child nodes
            // except for this clicked node.
            if (d.parent) {
                d.parent.children.forEach(function(element) {
                if (d !== element) {
                    collapse(element);
                }
                });
            }
            update(d);
            
          })
          .on("contextmenu", (d) => {
            d3.event.preventDefault();
            populateExplorerSidebar(d.id)
          });

          nodeEnter
          .append("rect")
          .attr("rx", 6)
          .attr("ry", 6)
          .attr("width", rectW)
          .attr("height", rectH)
          .style("stroke-width", 2)
          .attr("stroke", function (d) {
            if (d.status >= 0) {
                  t_hex = getInfoBoxColourHex(d.status / 10, false, 1, "");
                  return t_hex;

              } else {
                  return '#3d6571'
              }
          })
          .attr("stroke-width", 3)
          .style("border-radius", "10px")
          .style("opacity", function(d, i) {
            return !d.depth ? 0 : 1;
          })
          .style("pointer-events", function(d, i) {
            return !d.depth ? "none" : "all";
          })
          .style("fill", function (d) {
            if (d.status >= 0 && d._children) {
                t_rgb = getInfoBoxColourRgb(d.status / 10, false, 1, "");
                return t_rgb;
            } else {
                return '#f3f4f6'
            }
            });

          nodeEnter
          .append("text")
          .attr("x", rectW / 2)
          .attr("y", rectH / 2)
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .style("font-size", (d) => {
              if (d.name != null && d.name.length >= 19) {
                d.name = `${d.name.substring(0, 19)}...`
                return "6px"
              } else if (d.name != null && d.name.length >= 17) {
                  return "6px"
              } else if (d.name != null && d.name.length >= 14) {
                  return "8px"
              } else {
                  return "9px"
              }
          })
          .style("font-weight", "bold")
          .text(function (d) {
              return d.name;
          });

          // Transition nodes to their new position.
          var nodeUpdate = node
          .transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("transform", function (d) {
              return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
          });

          nodeUpdate
          .select("rect")
          .attr("rx", 6)
          .attr("ry", 6)
          .attr("width", rectW)
          .attr("height", rectH)
          .attr("stroke", function (d) {
              if (d.status >= 0) {
                  t_hex = getInfoBoxColourHex(d.status / 10, false, 1, "");
                  return t_hex;
              } else {
                  return '#3d6571'
              }
          })
          .attr("stroke-width", 3)
          .style("border-radius", "10px")
          .style("opacity", function(d, i) {
            return !d.depth ? 0 : 1;
          })
          .style("pointer-events", function(d, i) {
            return !d.depth ? "none" : "all";
          })
          .style("fill", function (d) {
            if (d.status >= 0 && d._children) {
                t_rgb = getInfoBoxColourRgb(d.status / 10, false, 1, "");
                return t_rgb;
            } else {
                return '#f3f4f6'
            }
            });

          nodeUpdate.select("text").style("fill-opacity", 1);

          // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
          var nodeExit = node
          .exit()
          .transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("transform", function (d) {
              return "translate(" + source.x + "," + source.y + ")";
          })
          .remove();

          nodeExit
          .select("rect")
          .attr("width", rectW)
          .attr("height", rectH)
          //.attr("width", bbox.getBBox().width)""
          //.attr("height", bbox.getBBox().height)
          .attr("stroke", "black")
          .attr("stroke-width", 1);

          nodeExit.select("text");

          // Update the links…
          var link = svg.selectAll("path.link").data(links, function (d) {
          return d.target.id;
          });

          // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
          link
          .enter()
          .insert("path", "g")
          .attr("class", "link")
          .attr("x", rectW / 2)
          .attr("y", rectH / 2)
          .style("opacity", function(d, i) {
            return !d.source.depth ? 0 : 1;
          })
          .style("pointer-events", function(d, i) {
            return !d.source.depth ? "none" : "all";
          })
          .attr("d", function (d) {
              var o = {
              x: source.x0,
              y: source.y0,
              };
              return diagonal({
              source: o,
              target: o,
              });
          });

          // Transition links to their new position.
          link.transition().duration(duration).attr("d", diagonal);

          // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
          link
          .exit()
          .transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("d", function (d) {
              var o = {
              x: source.x,
              y: source.y,
              };
              return diagonal({
              source: o,
              target: o,
              });
          })
          .remove();

          // Stash the old positions for transition.
          nodes.forEach(function (d) {
          d.x0 = d.x;
          d.y0 = d.y;
          });
      }
      // Redraw for zoom
      function redraw() {
          //console.log("here", d3.event.translate, d3.event.scale);
          svg.attr(
              "transform",
              "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")"
          );
      }
```

Attempt at refactor:

```
   var controlsData = data
    // Data
    var treeData = {
        name: null,
        children: controlsData,
    };
    
    // Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
    var margin = {top: -95, right: 440, bottom: 20, left: 440},
        width = 000 - margin.right - margin.left,
        height = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
    
    var svg = d3.select("#explorer-graph-container").append("svg")
        .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMax meet")
        .attr("viewBox", "0 0 1000 520"),
        g = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
    var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    rectW = 80,
    rectH = 30,
    root;

    // declares a tree layout and assigns the size
    var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

    // Assigns parent, children, height, depth
    root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) { return d.children; });
    root.x0 = 0;
    root.y0 = height / 2;

    // Collapse after the second level
    root.children.forEach(collapse);

    update(root);


    // Collapse the node and all it's children
    function collapse(d) {
        if(d.children) {
            d._children = d.children
            d._children.forEach(collapse)
            d.children = null
        }
    }

    function update(source) {
        // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
        var treeData = treemap(root);

        // Compute the new tree layout.
        var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
            links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

        // Normalize for fixed-depth.
        nodes.forEach(function(d){ d.y = !d.depth ? d.depth * 0 : d.depth * 100;});

        // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

        // Update the nodes...
        var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
            .data(nodes, function(d) {return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

        // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
        var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
            .attr('class', 'node')
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")";
        })
        .on('click', click);

        // Add Circle for the nodes
        nodeEnter.append('circle')
            .attr('class', 'node')
            .attr('r', 1e-6)
            .style("opacity", function(d, i) {
                return !d.depth ? 0 : 1;
            })
            .style("pointer-events", function(d, i) {
                return !d.depth ? "none" : "all";
            })
            .style("fill", function(d) {
                return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
            });

        // Add labels for the nodes
        nodeEnter.append('text')
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .attr("x", function(d) {
                return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
            })
            .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
                return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
            })
            .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

        // UPDATE
        var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

        // Transition to the proper position for the node
        nodeUpdate.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) { 
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        });

        // Update the node attributes and style
        nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
        .attr('r', 10)
        .style("opacity", function(d, i) {
            return !d.depth ? 0 : 1;
        })
        .style("pointer-events", function(d, i) {
            return !d.depth ? "none" : "all";
        })
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
        })
        .attr('cursor', 'pointer');


        // Remove any exiting nodes
        var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + source.x + "," + source.y + ")";
            })
            .remove();

        // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
        nodeExit.select('circle')
        .attr('r', 1e-6);

        // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
        nodeExit.select('text')
        .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

        // ****************** links section ***************************

        // Update the links...
        var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
            .data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });

        // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
        var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .style("opacity", function(d, i) {
                return !d.source.depth ? 0 : 1;
            })
            .style("pointer-events", function(d, i) {
                return !d.source.depth ? "none" : "all";
            })
            .attr('d', function(d){
            var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0}
            return diagonal(o, o)
            });

        // UPDATE
        var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

        // Transition back to the parent element position
        linkUpdate.transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr('d', function(d){ return diagonal(d, d.parent) });

        // Remove any exiting links
        var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr('d', function(d) {
            var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y}
            return diagonal(o, o)
            })
            .remove();

        // Store the old positions for transition.
        nodes.forEach(function(d){
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
        });

        // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
        function diagonal(s, d) {
            path = `M ${s.x} ${s.y}
                    C ${(s.x + d.x) / 2} ${s.y},
                    ${(s.x + d.x) / 2} ${d.y},
                    ${d.x} ${d.y}`

            return path
        }

        // Toggle children on click.
        function click(d) {
        if (d.children) {
            d._children = d.children;
            d.children = null;
            } else {
            d.children = d._children;
            d._children = null;
            }
        update(d);
        }
    }
```

I guess the main thing I would like to know is there an easier way off updating my code rather than starting from scratch